# Trying to set up Amazon MWS in Coldfusion. Super simple request not getting authorized

Tags: coldfusion, amazon-mws

I’m just trying to get something up and running in Amazon MWS with Coldfusion. Here is the code I’m using… super simple. When I replace the querystring part with an exact query string from the Amazon MWS scratchpad webpage, I get the EXACT same signature… so I know my signature code is working. But despite that, the only response I ever get from amazon is “The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.” So I’m just thinking it's somehow in the way I’m sending it rather than the actual signature. I’ve tried a ton of different things and spent so much time, but I never get any other response even though I can get the signature to exactly match that of an example run on scratchpad.

Here is my code with obviously the relevant private data as variables that I have filled in in my actual code: (note I have to add 5 hours to my server’s time to make amazon happy with the request time so you might have to change that)

```
<CFSET nowtime = DateAdd(‘h’, 5, Now())>
<CFSET awsaccesskey = “”>
<CFSET sellerid = “”>
<CFSET secretkey = “”>
<CFSET mwsaccess = “”>

<CFSET queryString = “AWSAccessKeyId=#awsaccesskey#&Action=ListAllFulfillmentOrders&MWSAuthToken=#mwsaccess#&QueryStartDateTime=2020-04-12T04%3A00%3A00Z&SellerId=#sellerid#&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=#dateFormat(nowtime, ‘yyyy-mm-dd’)#T#encodeForURL(timeFormat(nowtime, ‘HH:mm:ss’))#Z&Version=2010-10-01”>
<CFSET signaturestring = “POST#chr(10)#mws.amazonservices.com#chr(10)#/FulfillmentOutboundShipment/2010-10-01#chr(10)##listSort(queryString, ‘text’, ‘asc’, ‘&’)#”>
<CFSET signature = encodeForURL(toBase64(binaryDecode(hmac(signaturestring, “#secretkey#”, “HmacSHA256”, “UTF-8”), “hex”)))>
<CFHTTP method=“POST” url=“https://mws.amazonservices.com/FulfillmentOutboundShipment/2010-10-01/?#queryString#&Signature=#signature#” >
  <cfhttpparam type=“Header” name=“Content-Type” value=“application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8”/>
  <cfhttpparam type=“Header” name=“x-amazon-user-agent” value=“Whatever/test (Language=Coldfusion)”/>
</CFHTTP>
<CFDUMP var="#CFHTTP.FileContent#" />
```

It’s a super simple request… but I just can’t get anywhere with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

*sigh*.  A guy on the Amazon forums figured it out for me. His handle is Autonomoose. Anyway, I have a / in the CFHTTP post line.  this one:

```
<CFHTTP method=“POST” url=“https://mws.amazonservices.com/FulfillmentOutboundShipment/2010-10-01/?#queryString#&Signature=#signature#” >
```

Where it says 2010-10-01/?...  That / there.  Delete it and the whole thing works.